# Gear lever fouls on bracket mounting the assembly to the handlebar

Tags: shifter

The lower derailleur gear lever on the right side of the handlebar fouls on the mounting bracket securing the whole gear/brake cable assembly to the handlebar. At present, I cannot change gear with that lower lever. I guess the lever has been bent inwards on impact with something.
Should I try to bend the lever away from the bracket so that it can move freely, or is there another way?

Comment: A photo will help us provide good answers

Comment: Photo, please.   Are you aware of ever having crashed this bike ?